# SSD suddenly stopped booting

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I had Samsung 860 EVO 250Gb SSD installed on my PC, probably for more than 1 year. I run Windows 10. It worked just fine. There was no errors, read/write speed was consistent.

One week ago, I booted my PC and "Reboot and Select proper boot device" error appeared. I booted from Debian live DVD, and it was throwing `SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }` during boot. I tried reconnecting my SSD and checking cables, and it worked. I forgot about it until yesterday. This error has appeared again.

I tried plugging it into another sata port, changing cables, nothing helped. Linux was throwing the same error. And when I connected this drive to another PC running linux, everything worked just fine, there were no errors, I could read data and when I brought it back to the PC where it had errors, it just booted up. But when I rebooted it once again, this error was back.

I didn't install any new hardware, nor changed any BIOS settings.

What could be wrong? Is my SSD or motherboard faulty or something wrong with my Windows setup? I have a spare motherboard, so I could try replacing it.

Comment: Try another SATA cable. Make sure there is no strain on either end of the plugs/sockets.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm 98% sure that the problem isn't in the cable, because I've tried another one and there was the same issue, but SSD also worked on another pc with the same cable.

Comment: If the live DVD is affected too, then it's not the drive. Have a memtest86 drive at hand and run it when the issue comes back.

Comment: @gronostaj Hmm, I thought that live DVD was throwing errors because it tried to mount my SSD.

Comment: @Lowder It shouldn't mount it on boot, and even if it did for some reason it should fail gracefully. No reason to halt the boot on a non-critical error.

Comment: @gronostaj It was throwing errors during the boot, but it eventually booted into recovery mode. Although, Windows repair didn't boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everyone! I finally fixed it! The problem wasn't in my hardware. My SSD and motherboard are working properly now. I managed to fix it by rebuilding BCD from the live DVD.
https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the "SMART" attributes of your ssd , using gnome disk or crystal disk(windows).See if you have any attributes that have been exceeded .There is a firmware for the 860EVO on samsung's site which you could try ,but it may reduce performance from initial reports.

Also check your psu , if its old it might be sending extra ripple down the 12v ,5v and 3.3v lines.The SSD being a microchip is very sensitive to bad voltage, and unstable voltage can lockup chips or change their behaviour to act strange.

Also check your memory , if your ram is going bad(general system instability).